# Exclude @npm// Dependencies from Bazel Dependency Graph (bazel query)

Tags: graph, bazel, bazel-query

I use the following commands to generate a graph for my Bazel project.

```
bazel query 'deps(//services/gateway:lib)' --output graph --nohost_deps --noimplicit_deps > graph.in
dot -Tpng < graph.in > graph.png
```

The following graph is generated:

```
digraph mygraph {
  node [shape=box];
  "//services/gateway:lib"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "//services/gateway:controllers/auth.controller.ts\n//services/gateway:index.ts\n//services/gateway:controllers/index.controller.ts\n//:tsconfig.json\n//services/gateway:controllers/index.ts"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//@types/node:node"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//inversify-express-utils:inversify-express-utils"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//helmet:helmet"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//inversify:inversify"
  "@npm//inversify:inversify"
  "@npm//inversify:inversify" -> "@npm//inversify:inversify__contents"
  "@npm//inversify:inversify" -> "@npm//inversify:inversify__files"
  "@npm//inversify:inversify" -> "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:host_windows"
  
   MANY MORE LINES

 "@npm//:node_modules/bytes/index.js\n@npm//:node_modules/bytes/History.md\n@npm//:node_modules/bytes/Readme.md\n@npm//:node_modules/bytes/LICENSE\n@npm//:node_modules/bytes/package.json"
  "@npm//methods:methods__nested_node_modules"
  "@npm//array-flatten:array-flatten__files"
  "@npm//array-flatten:array-flatten__files" -> "@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/LICENSE\n@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/array-flatten.js\n@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/README.md\n@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/package.json"
  "@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/LICENSE\n@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/array-flatten.js\n@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/README.md\n@npm//:node_modules/array-flatten/package.json"
}
```

As you can see this graph is ridiculously huge, because of all those dependencies from `@npm//<something>`
[image: ra]

What I actually want is something like this:

```
digraph mygraph {
  node [shape=box];
  "//services/gateway:lib"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "//services/gateway:controllers/auth.controller.ts\n//services/gateway:index.ts\n//services/gateway:controllers/index.controller.ts\n//:tsconfig.json\n//services/gateway:controllers/index.ts"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//@types/node:node"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//inversify-express-utils:inversify-express-utils"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//helmet:helmet"
  "//services/gateway:lib" -> "@npm//inversify:inversify"
}
```

[image: good graph]

---

**Is it possible to remove all those npm-dependencies in the graph without manually removing them from the graph.in file?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you describe the targets you're interested in (e.g. with `deps()`), you should be able to [ask for](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#expressions) more or (in this case less):

```
deps(//services/gateway:lib) except @npm//...:*
```

or:

```
deps(//services/gateway:lib) - @npm//...:*
```